# $.post запрос на сервер

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, участники сообщества, мне бы хотелось задать вам следующий вопрос: Я методом post отправляю серверу запрос и по задумке, получаю либо код, либо ничего) Как мне оформить скрипт таким образом, чтобы если сервер не вернул мне код, а вернул к примеру слово "none", то мне стоит прекратить выполнение скрипта, а если вернул код, то собственно продолжить работу?

```
$.post("/cart/tableProductsAjax/", {}, function (data)
{
    $("#cart_div").html(data);
});
```

и какой тип имеет data ? Может быть не зная этого, я не могу правильно написать if...

Comment: `if ( data == 'none' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возвращаемая data будет того типа, что определено на сервере. Если это 'none' - то строка.

```js
$.post('/').done(function(data){
  if(data === 'none'){ //Если сервер вернул 'none'
    console.info('Ничего не найдено');
    return;//Предотвращает дальнейшее исполнение
  }
  
  $(document).html(data); //Продолжаем работу с пришедшими данными
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```